# Small parts of a pixel not showing WITHIN the boundaries of the shapefile, when a clip function is applied to an image collection in GEE

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, clip

I am trying to clip a sea-surface temperature (SST) dataset to the coastal waters surrounding the Australian coastline. I have done this fairly successfully, but in a few small areas the SST pixel is not showing (despite being visible before a clip is applied).

I am guessing that there must be some sort of filter applied where if only a tiny bit of the 4km pixel is within the boundaries of the geometry clip then it is not visualized?

The clip works fine for the bathymetry layer included.

Is there anything that I can do to change this, so these small patches are included?

```
var vic_waters = ee.FeatureCollection('users/s3825806/Vic_Waters')
Map.setCenter(142.27321357334174,-38.37308591015567, 13); 
Map.addLayer(vic_waters, {color: 'orange'}, 'Vic_waters', false);
    
var GCOM = ee.ImageCollection('JAXA/GCOM-C/L3/OCEAN/SST/V3')
                    .filter(ee.Filter.date('2023-01-01', '2023-04-01'));
var seaSurfaceTemperature =GCOM.select('SST_AVE');
var SST = seaSurfaceTemperature.mean().multiply(0.0012).add(-10).clip(vic_waters);
Map.addLayer(SST, {min: 0.0,   max: 30.0, palette: ['000000', '005aff', '43c8c8', 'fff700', 'ff0000']}, 'SST');

var Bathy = ee.Image('users/s3825806/Victorian-coast_Bathy_10m')
var Bathymetry = Bathy.select('b1').clip(vic_waters);
Map.addLayer (Bathymetry, {min:-118,    max: 730.255126953125}, 'Bathymetry')
```

Code link:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ee7b4295877c5df4921722f00af79f04

[image: Screenshot, Green is SST, orange shows the shapefile where the SST is missing]

Comment: In the raster model, there is no such thing as a "small part of a pixel" -- pixels are atomic. Either it's within or it's not. And the usual factor is whether the center is within. Assuming the pixels are square, a buffer of sqrt(pixel_size) will handle most boundary conditions.

Comment: Thanks @Vince for your advice. The pixels are 4km and the coastal waters shapefile buffer covers the 1km from the coastline, so it could definitely be that the pixel centre is outside the coastal waters. The pixels are square. I would appreciate it if you would further explain your solution as I am a beginner to gee and have not had boundary issues before, and am not sure how to apply a buffer of sqrt(pixel_size)? Thanks Vince.

Comment: Your collections, `users/s3825806/Vic_Waters` and `users/s3825806/Victorian-coast_Bathy_10m`, are not shared.

Comment: Thanks @DanielWiell i have just changed access to anyone can read, i hope that is what is required?

Comment: That part is missing from the original, unclipped dataset, as far as I can tell. You have to go back to around 2022-07-01 to find something in that area.

Comment: Thanks @DanielWiell. That specific date works! So why would the part be missing when the period of time is extended for the whole off 2022 (inc. covering this period)? A mean of the year should show it I would have thought? Appreciate the help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the specifics of that data set, so I cannot be of any help with that.

Comment: Thanks @DanielWiell. I have tried swapping the dataset for other global sea surface temp datasets and similar patchiness there too, so i will persist. But it's helpful to know there is a data factor involved, so thanks for pointing me in that direction.